# UndefinedFunctionException - Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"

Tags: php, symfony, apcu

I am trying to run

```
app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql
```

using Symfony 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP7. The above command throws the following **error:**

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]
>
> Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache".

The following post do list similar issues - without a working solution (from my point of view)

- [Symfony 2 - Attempted to call function "apcu_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054900/symfony-2-attempted-to-call-function-apcu-fetch-from-namespace-doctrine-com)
- [Attempted to call function "apc_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017218/attempted-to-call-function-apc-fetch-from-namespace-doctrine-common-cache)

I have `php-apcu` installed, `php -m` outputs:

```
[PHP Modules]
apcu
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

The output of  `php -r 'phpinfo();' |grep apc` is:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
apcu
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.writable => /tmp => /tmp
```

So my conclusion is - the APCU module is loaded but i still get the UndefinedFunctionException.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

apc_fetch() is a function in the now deprecated apc module.
To use it with apcu on php7, use pecl to install the apcu_bc package.

http://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc

Additionally, add the line

```
extension=apc.so
```

to your php.ini (or your apcu.ini).
This will provide backward compatibility with the apc module.

Comment: Thanks - that solved the problem. Installed via `sudo pecl install pecl/apcu_bc-1.0.3`

Comment: If you already have apcu installed then you have to uninstall it first and then run "pecl install pecl/apcu_bc-1.0.3"